# Chat (non-mobile view) scrolls up and down rapidly on iPad

Tags: bug, chat, ipad

I prefer using the non-mobile view of chat on my iPad (in mobile Safari). The mobile version is great on my phone, but it wastes a lot of space and I end up missing the enhanced functionality on the larger iPad screen.

But the non-mobile version is frequently unusable, because the room bounces incessantly. It loads correctly (with the last bit of the transcript and the compose message box at the bottom) then scrolls rapidly up to the top before bouncing back to the bottom. Lather, rinse, repeat. I can use it if I can "catch" it, and scroll it up a tiny bit (instead of all the way to the top), and then back down to the bottom. (Until it starts happening again.)

This happens in multiple rooms on chat.MSE - and did before the move on chat.MSO - and has persisted through several software updates on my iPad.

Comment: The resolution is to convince balpha to let me make all sorts of usability tweaks to chat, of course. Take the burden off his shoulders and what not.

Comment: Think it's because of resize events getting into endless loop.

Comment: This is greatly improved in iOS 8. Or maybe someone fixed it without saying anything right around the time I updated iOS. Does it still happen for others? Is it happening on other tablet OSs?

Comment: Have you noticed this problem on Android, or other platforms, by chance (if you use any others)? It seems to work fine on my Kindle Fire 2, so far, although I haven't tested it much. Also, the description of the chat is truncated, and I don't see a way to get it from the mobile version.